# prevent zend tools from shifting controller files

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, action

so whenever i create a new action on zend tools...zend tools would for some reason shift the source code of the other actions right hence disturbing the aesthetic flow of the code....is there a way to prevent this from happening

I am using zend framework on apache in windows

Comment: +1. I have the same problem on Linux, however does not happen all the time, but it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use zend tools.  It's not that hard to add new actions by hand. . . in fact it takes less time then deleting extra whitespace from your files. Additionally, Zend Tools does not support deleting the actions it creates, and you will have to manually go into your zfproject.xml file to remove anything you've deleted. IMO Zend Tools only exists to win over Rails programmers, and while it's great to get a project started, it's not practical for any serious work.

Comment: I agree, I start out and create my basic controllers and actions (using Zend_Tool), then I just manually add/delete them when refactoring.